# Want to stop moving the player Object after Collision with an Obstacle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm new to Unity, and I am now at collision in Unity. I am trying that, when my player object (which is moving) hits an obstacle, it stops moving. However, after searching so many tutorials, I couldn't find anything.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("WE HIT AN OBSTACLE");
    }
}
```

I added this code in my Player object and ran it, but there's nothing in the console. What changes should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a script to move your player, you can just disable the script when collision happens.
Say we have the script `PlayerMovement`.

```
public PlayerMovement playerMovement;       
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    playerMovement.enabled = false;
}
```

in this case you should assign `PlayerMovement`component in Unity.
in another case, you can get `PlayerMovement` component in script:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
   if(collision.gameObject.tag.Contains("Player")
   collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`OnCollisionEnter` is called when this collider/rigidbody has begun touching another rigidbody/collider.

> In contrast to OnTriggerEnter, OnCollisionEnter is passed the Collision class and not a Collider. The Collision class contains information, for example, about contact points and impact velocity. **Notes: Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached**. Collision events will be sent to disabled MonoBehaviours, to allow enabling Behaviours in response to collisions.

Source: [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)